Concept placement changes program outcome without compile error, possible to avoid?
I thought I wrote a nice concept, but then before the commit I reordered where it was in my file and suddenly, the program result was wrong (without any compilation errors)!
Here's a code sample to match what I had, trying to do a special compare in some cases:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace
{
    //Put CanDoSpecialCompare here, and the end result is different ("Same int, Different vector"))!
    
    template<typename T>
    bool SpecialCompare(const std::vector<T>& first, const std::vector<T>& second) {
        return true; //Dummy implementation
    }

    //Put CanDoSpecialCompare here, and the end result is different ("Same int, Same vector"))!
    template <typename T>
    concept CanDoSpecialCompare = requires(T a, T b) {
        SpecialCompare(a,b);
    };

    template<CanDoSpecialCompare T>
    bool Compare(const T& a, const T& b) {
        return SpecialCompare(a, b);
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool Compare(const T& a, const T& b) {
        return a == b;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2}, v2{1,3};    
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 1;
    
    if (Compare(i1,i2))
        std::cout << "Same int, ";
    else 
        std::cout << "Different int, ";

    if (Compare(v1,v2))
        std::cout << "Same vector" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "Different vector" << std::endl;
}

fiddle
I sort of see why this happens (defining the concept before the function it tests for, so it doesn't "see" the function?), but not completely (it's a template that is used only after the SpecialCompare function template it needs, so at the moment I use the concept, it should see the SpecialCompare function template?).
Also, what could I do if I wanted to have the concept at the top, or better, how can I write this so that the concept can be moved without issue? I think I could also use a trait, but my impression was always that concepts were the more readable/shorter equivalent of that?

SpecialCompare(a,b); can only see previous declaration or use ADL to find it, but ADL only brings std for std::vector.

Typo: "Same int": it would be 1 == 1 for regular compare, or SpecialCompare(1, 1) (i.e true), you probably want i2 = 2 but anyway, there are no SpecialCompare for int.

@Jarod42 So if the declaration has to be visible at the point of concept definition, not its instantiation, does that mean a and b are not considered templated entities? Is this the IFNDR case (every type produces substitution failure)?

@Yksisarvinen: There is still ADL, but SpecialCompare is not in a appropriate namespace to be found for std::vector<int>, it should be in namespace std, which is forbidden. So the remaining possibilities is to be placed before the concept.

Hmm yes, the int part doesn't matter here, that was just to make thing make a little more sense. The idea is that that's a type that doesn't need a special compare.

As already mentioned in comments, the concept can only see names declared before itself, or introduced by ADL - and name lookup failure just counts as evaluating to false (after all, there could be a SpecialCompare introduced via ADL for some T).
The easy solution is to add a sanity check such as
template <typename T>
concept CanDoSpecialCompare = requires(T a, T b) {
        SpecialCompare(a,b);
};
static_assert(CanDoSpecialCompare<std::vector<int>>);

right after the concept.

Thanks, the static assert seems like a great way to ensure I don't accidentally break things!

This isn't directly about concepts. Any template placed there would have the same issue.
The first question you should ask yourself is: "Is SpecialCompare a customization point?".
If it is one (if the user can provide their own overloads), then your approach is flawed, because the rest of your code (not only the concept) might not see the user overloads, depending on the include order. You should switch to a different mechanism, such as:

Replacing it with a class template and specializing it (like std::hash)

Keeping the function, but making sure all calls go through ADL.
This would require no changes to the code if only the owner of a
type could provide SpecialCompare for it (in their namespace), but
here it's clearly not the case, because you're trying to provide it
for std::vector which you don't own.
There is a hack to work around this: add a dummy parameter (e.g. struct tag {};) of a type declared in your namespace (global namespace in this case, but consider moving this to an actual namespace), which will make ADL consider both your namespace and the type's namespace.


Or, if SpecialCompare isn't a customization point, just order things the right way (the concept and all templates after all overloads of SpecialCompare).
In any case, document whether SpecialCompare is a customization point or not.

Thanks, it's not a customization point luckily. I was looking for a way to prevent breaking things with my own tendency to make the order of things "nicer". The static assert from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79294152/109787 seems like a great way to make sure that doesn't happen again.
The hack with the dummy would be even better in a way, because then I could put the concepts where I feel I want them, but it also looks a bit strange to do that just to put things in an order that feels better, so I'm not sure yet if I want to go there.

@Legolas FYI https://gcc.godbolt.org/ is a popular alternative and has short links.

Here's what I put together with the hack mentioned: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tz9doMPrM

@Legolas Looks good. If this is in a header you'll also need constexpr or inline on the variable.
